# How do I get JAWS to read the dialog header if the focus goes to a menu-item within the dialog?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader, wcag2.0

My pop-up is of the following structure. It's a dialog where the focus **should** go to first menu-item (Item 1)

```
<div role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dheader">
  <span id="dheader" role="heading" aria-level="1">Actions </span>
  <div role="menu">
     <a id="a" role="menu-item" href="somelink">Item 1</a>
     <a id="b" role="menu-item" href="somelink">Item 2</a>
     <a id="c" role="menu-item" href="somelink">Item 3</a>
     <a id="d" role="menu-item" href="somelink">Item 4</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is JAWS ignores the role=dialog since it sees a role="menu". Therefore it just announces "Entering Menu Item 1" I want it to read "Actions Dialog Entering Menu Item 1"

Is this possible in anyway apart from adding an `aria-describedby` for the first item to point to the heading?

Comment: Just a side note, if you don't have an href= in your <a>, then most browsers will not TAB to those items.  You'll need a tabindex='0'.  Which browsers did you have the JAWS problem with?  Did you try different browsers?

Comment: my bad. This was just an example. It does have a href=""